# C# message box - disappear automatically

Tags: c#

I have a windows application that will write some information to Track1 and Track2 of a card. Now what I would like to accomplish is that when the user clicks the button a messagebox appear saying "Waiting For Swipe" once user swipes the card for the messagebox to disappear.

I tried to use a do while loop however it will not see my function that I am calling

for example:

```
do{
readcard();
}while (messagebox.show());
```

this did not work at all. Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MessageBox.Show` shows a messagebox and waits for the user to dismiss it.

if you want to display something that doesn't wait for the user, but is controlled programmatically, you need to write it yourself.  In Windows Forms, you'd create a `Form`, perhaps with the winforms designer, call `Show` on an instance to show it, then `Hide` to hide it afterwards

*However*, windows applications and any applications written in the last... 10 or 20 years... are *event-driven* and so you if the user is involved you shouldn't use loops like that (with the `while`).

Check out:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming
http://dotnetfirez.blogspot.com/2010/05/winforms.html
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99842/vs2010-winform-designer-to-learn-or-bottom-up-approach

and Google for a starting point.

Comment: Yeah, MessageBox.show blocks the main thread so no other code could be ran to close it anyway and reading the swipe would have to be on a separate thread whilst the message box is open.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a basic small sized form. Put a label and enter your message there.Make the form's startposition property to center
- Call the form instance

  ```
  AutomaticDisappearPopup pop = new AutomaticDisappearPopup();        
  pop.Show();
  WaitSomeTime(pop);
  ```
- Define the waitSomeTime method for display time and then disappear without interrupting the main thread

  ```
  public async void WaitSomeTime(Form item)
  {
      await Task.Delay(3000);
      item.Close();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have created a wrapper for TopMost messagebox which can disappear after some time using WinForms MessageBox(usable also on WPF).

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MessageBox = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox;
using Size = System.Drawing.Size;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Views
{
    public class TopMostMessageBox
    {
        const int WM_CLOSE = 0x10;
        
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        public static DialogResult Show(string message, string title = null, MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon messageBoxIcon = MessageBoxIcon.None, int timeoutSeconds = -1, bool topMost = true )
        {
            title = title ?? String.Empty;
            Form timeoutMessageBox = CreateAutoCloseWindow(timeoutSeconds, topMost);

            return MessageBox.Show(timeoutMessageBox, message, title, buttons, messageBoxIcon);
        }
        
        private static Form CreateAutoCloseWindow(int timeoutSeconds, bool isTopMost = false)
        {
            var w = new Form() { Size = new Size(0, 0), TopMost = isTopMost};

            int timeoutMs =(timeoutSeconds == -1) ? -1 : (timeoutSeconds*1000);

            Task.Delay(timeoutMs).ContinueWith(
                t => ControlInvoke(w, () => SendMessage(w.Handle, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)));

            return w;
        }
        
        public static void ControlInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control control, Action action) //in case you work with multiple threads
        {
            try
            {
                if (control == null || action ==null) return;

                if (control.InvokeRequired) control.Invoke(new System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker(delegate { action(); }));
                else action();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"InvokeSelfFixedException: {e}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just call

```
TopMostMessageBox.Show("This is TOP_MOST messagebox text", "TOP_MOST title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
```